# PHP Can't Run Query on Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm not sure what's wrong with the following code. I'm trying to connect to MSSQL with PHP to run a query. The code can connect to the server and database, but fails on query execution. This code is virtually identical to the way I retrieve data from MySQL. What is the mistake I'm making here?

Thanks.

```
$link = mssql_connect ($server, $user, $password)
  or die ( "<h1>ERROR: Can't connect to MSSQL.</h1>");

$db_selected = mssql_select_db ($db, $link)
  or die ("<h1>ERROR: Can't read MSSQL database.</h1>");

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM [uStore].[dbo].[Store]';

$result = mssql_query ($sql)
  or die ("<h1>ERROR: Can't execute MSSQL query.</h1>");

echo 'ok';

mssql_free_result ($link);
```

Comment: Maybe put a `mssql_get_last_message()` before you exit your script in order to find out what the server has to say about the query.

Comment: Hi Bjoern. The function returned the error message: Invalid object name 'uStore.dbo.Store'. So the question now is why isn't this a valid object? Its taken from the query in Management Studio. I've tried different combinations for the database but nothing is being accepted.

Comment: maybe rephrase your question and add this little detail.